# DevTool filesystem doesn't map index.html the network resource to the local file

Tags: angular, google-chrome, frontend, devtools

i have a front end of a web app and i've noticed while printing in console that all logs are mapped to main.js instead of been linked to a specific component.

this is what i see in console.

```
main.js:14050
main.js:11311
main.js:11315
main.js:7613 
main.js:7613
```

[Console logs][1]

I've tried to go to Source - Filesystem and Add folder to workspace but everytime i don't have a green dot on index.html file. This means that a mapping between the local files and the network ones is not established.

[Source tab][2]

Any ideas what can i do to establish mapping in a right way?

Comment: sourcemaps aren't configured properly, that is why it doesn't show you the original file

Comment: thanks for showing a direction, JS sourcemaps were disabled. One flag and everything works!

Answer (score 0):

F12 -> Settings -> Preferences -> Sources -> Enable Javascript source maps